# virtualenv choosing python version gives permission denied error

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I would like to specify the python version of the virtualenv. I have installed python `2.7` and `3.8` through home brew and I can create virtual environments like it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv) like so for both versions:

`virtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 my-env`

To now use other python versions e.g. `3.7` many pages recommend `pyenv`. I can install a specific python version using `pyenv` however when I want to use it in a similar fashion:

`virtualenv --python=/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7 my-env`

I get `RuntimeError: failed to query /Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7 with code 13 err: 'Permission denied'`

I also tried to activate the `pyenv` environment globally and use that to install. I can successfully change my python version in the terminal using `pyenv`. However after creating the virtual environment it always uses the true python installed and not the one from `pyenv`.

Why do I get a permission denied for something that is installed in my home folder?
I never used sudo to install any of these things explicitly. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Ok I now found it out. It must link to the python binary like so:

`virtualenv --python=/Users/user/.pyenv/versions/3.7.7/bin/python ~/.virtualenvs/my-project`

The reason why it worked with the brew installed versions was that `/usr/bin/python2.7` is actually a symlinks not a folder.